# Вывести график в котором будут данные за определенный период с периодичностью час/месяц/день

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, график, анализ-данных

[image: данные csv]
[Ссылка для скачивания данных](https://yadi.sk/d/kZ3yB_k-G_4NDg)

Есть данные, в какое время покупают и продают.
Нужно построить график, в котором сравнивается, сколько покупок/продаж в месяц и в час (в дальнейшем будут разные функции которые выводят график либо за месяц, либо за день и т.д.).

---

По оси `х` должна быть дата со временем, по оси `у` сколько покупок/продаж:

```py
def BUYORSELL(date_start,data_end, dfBS):
    orders_Date = dfBS[((dfBS['date_Open'] >= date_start)&(dfBS['date_Open'] < data_end)) | ((dfBS['date_Open'] < date_start)&(dfBS['date_Closed']> date_start))]
    orders_BUY = len(orders_Date.query("trade_Type == 'BUY'"))
    orders_SELL = len(orders_Date.query("trade_Type == 'SELL'"))
    print('BUY = ',orders_BUY,'SELL = ', orders_SELL)

    df_visual = orders_Date.groupby('trade_Type')['date_Open'].count()
    df_visual.plot(kind='bar')
    plt.show()

df = pd.read_csv('testtraders.csv', header = 0, sep= ',')
df['date_Open'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_Open'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
df['date_Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_Closed'], format = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')


date_start = '2019/10/11 00:00:00'
date_obj_s = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_start, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
date_end = '2019/11/25 23:55:55'
date_obj_e = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_end, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
BUYORSELL(date_obj_s,date_obj_e, df )
```

Мой код выводит, сколько всего за определенный период, т.е. без периодичности.

[image: результат кода]

Comment: я изменила вопрос (добавила ссылку для скачивания) спасибо большое что уделяете время

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

Исходный DF:

```
In [42]: df
Out[42]:
           id   trade_Id trade_Type           date_Open         date_Closed
0   435187142  519059867        BUY 2019-12-05 18:36:12 2019-12-05 20:50:01
1   435097135  518663229       SELL 2019-12-02 19:05:06 2019-12-04 17:05:41
2   434908884  518144335       SELL 2019-11-25 14:05:50 2019-12-02 16:51:35
3   434908883  518565206       SELL 2019-11-29 18:58:56 2019-12-02 16:51:35
4   434432835  517746855       SELL 2019-11-20 11:38:03 2019-11-21 19:33:05
5   434432836  517831499       SELL 2019-11-21 06:03:08 2019-11-21 19:33:05
6   434253086  517652280       SELL 2019-11-19 12:26:37 2019-11-19 13:39:18
7   434097446  517172951        BUY 2019-11-13 12:15:43 2019-11-15 14:09:25
8   434097445  517307912        BUY 2019-11-14 14:08:27 2019-11-15 14:09:25
9   433862167  517068573       SELL 2019-11-12 13:35:46 2019-11-12 18:46:09
10  433708357  516497545       SELL 2019-11-05 12:33:51 2019-11-08 15:19:55
11  433708358  516513056       SELL 2019-11-07 22:34:26 2019-11-08 15:19:55
12  433424921  516271436       SELL 2019-11-01 11:53:24 2019-11-05 03:51:52
13  433310805  516146493       SELL 2019-10-31 02:06:50 2019-10-31 23:34:03
14  433196571  515552502        BUY 2019-10-22 22:11:50 2019-10-30 19:08:33
15  432823321  515193801       SELL 2019-10-17 18:23:23 2019-10-22 17:16:43
16  432823322  515320592       SELL 2019-10-19 01:58:03 2019-10-22 17:16:43
17  432571018  514638826       SELL 2019-10-11 21:53:43 2019-10-17 12:32:51
18  432183778  514590774       SELL 2019-10-11 17:00:32 2019-10-11 21:02:51
```

решение:

```
(df.groupby([df["date_Open"].dt.month_name(), "trade_Type"])
   .size()
   .to_frame("trade_Type")
   ["trade_Type"]
   .unstack()
   .plot.bar(rot=0, grid=True))
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо большое!
чтобы сделать по часам нужно freq="H" использовать?